# django.db.utils.operationalError: (2059,"Authentication Plugin 'caching_sha2_password'")

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am trying to connect my django project 'mysite' to mysql. I made a user in mysql and granted it all privileges to access the project. These are the changes I made to settings.py :

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'mysitedb',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
}
}
```

Now when I try to migrate the database using `python3 manage.py makemigrations`, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")</code></pre>
```

The complete stack trace is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 236, in get_new_connection
return Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 332, in execute
self.check()
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 27, in check_all_models
errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1200, in check
errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1272, in _check_fields
errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 894, in check
errors = super().check(**kwargs)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 206, in check
errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 303, in _check_backend_specific_checks
return connections[db].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/validation.py", line 21, in check_field
field_type = field.db_type(self.connection)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 648, in db_type
return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 133, in data_types
if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision:
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 65, in supports_microsecond_precision
return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 345, in mysql_version
with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 576, in temporary_connection
cursor = self.cursor()
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
return self._cursor()
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
self.ensure_connection()
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/home/prabhjeet/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 236, in get_new_connection
return Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")
```

How can I resolve this error? I am using python 3 on ubuntu 16.04 platform.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, there is no need to downgrade the MYSQL Server. Follow these two steps and it should work:

Step 1: Change MYSQL configuration to use mysql_native_password. Edit one of ini files that mysqld is using. You can see which one my using the command

```
mysqld --verbose --help
```

and make sure this line is added -

```
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Step 2: Create an new or alter the existing user. To create a new with mysql_native_password password:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'ip_address' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

and to alter user

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'ip_address' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

By the way, this step is also pointed out by @Kol_ya

Comment: the Alter command worked perfectly. I altered the 'root' ID that gets created by default when installing MySQL

Comment: I got this `ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'sms_db_user'@'127.0.0.1' `. Also`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password' at line 1`

Answer (score 6):

The issue is (probably) your (new) version of MySQL.

Starting with version 8.04 MySQL uses caching_sha2_password as default authentication plugin where previously mysql_native_password has been used (which causes compatibility issues with older services that expect mysql_native_password authentication).

Possible solutions:

Downgrade the MySQL Server to a version below that change or change the authentication plugin (on a user basis)

eg when creating the user:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: getting error 'access denied , USING_PASSWORD: yes' altough password is entered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

@Kol_ya created new user using CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'; where username = creation of new username and password = current password to login for root(username created with caching_sha2). This step allowed me to connect to MySql Server 8.0.13 without having caching_sha2 authentication error.
Looked for solution several threads but this one helped just like that. Thanks @kol_ya

Suggestion to people who are having caching_sha2 issue. In server side make sure your user authentication type is standard not caching_sha2_password.

Answer (score 0):

In MySql 8.0 the default authentication plugin is 'caching_sha2_password', which causes authentication plugin issues(error 2059), one can create a new user in the MySql workbench
and setting there Authentication to be standard.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the authentication mechanism for the user we are trying to login. Below is the screen reference set it to standard. Change Authentication Type to standard from caching_sha2_password. For the given user.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

This error is typically gotten when the DB user don't have all access to the database

Run this command:

```
ALTER  USER 'username'@'ip_address' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

*Make sure to have your MySQL server running.