# (2059,“Authentication Plugin 'caching_sha2_password'”) when running server connected with MYSQL database on Django

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector, pymysql

I want to configure my django project in order to connect it with database in **MYSQL** I created with **workbench 8.0**,
 and then I want to run the server by running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

from anaconda command prompt,
 
so that I can use the Django interface to visualize and alter data.
Please note that I don’t want to downgrade workbench 8.0.

These are the steps I have made:

From anaconda prompt:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

In my project folder, in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'schema_meta',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '<mypassword>',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
}
```

Inside the directory of mysql server, I open cnf.ini and insert a the [client] section:

```
[client]
database=schema_meta
host=127.0.0.1
user=root
password=<mypassword>
port=3306
default-character-set = utf8
```

Then from anaconda prompt I run

```
Python manage.py runserver
```

And I obtain error

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin
>   'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: Impossibile trovare il
>   modulo specificato.\r\n")

So I try to solve it by following this thread:
 [django.db.utils.operationalError: (2059,"Authentication Plugin 'caching_sha2_password'")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469587/django-db-utils-operationalerror-2059-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-pas?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I open mysql workbench and I run this query:

```
delete from mysql.user
where user='root'
and host = '127.0.0.1';
flush privileges;
CREATE  USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<mypassword>';
```

And then, in the my.ini file I change

```
default-authentication-plugin= caching_sha2_password
```

With

```
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Finally from anaconda prompt:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But again I get

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin
>   'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: Impossibile trovare il
>   modulo specificato.\r\n")

Now, what’s wrong? Why it did not get the changes into the authentication method?

In order to check that there are no other errors, from mysql workbench, from first “home” view, I right click on my database, I open “edit connection”, I click on “test connection”, and the software says that the connection is successfull.

[mysql workbench saying connection successfully established](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8wdH.png)

Moreover, I wanted to check if the problem was in my Django settings.
So from anaconda prompt I run

```
pip install pymysql
```

Then in the project folders I created a “connect_to_mysql.py” script, with the following code inside:

```
import pymysql.cursors
mydb = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             user='root',
                             password='<mypassword>',
                             db='schema_meta',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
print(mydb)
```

and this seems to work fine, since when I run

```
connect_to_mysql.py
```

from anaconda, I get

> pymysql.connections.Connection object at 0x000002013F2851D0

That I guess it means “connection successfully established”.
And just to be sure that the problem is into mysql (mysql connector I guess), I create a file “connect_to_mysql_2.py” with this code inside:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='<mypassword>',
                             host='127.0.0.1', database='meta_schema')
print(mydb)
```

And when I run it from anaconda, again I get

> "Authentication plugin '{0}' is not supported".format(plugin_name))
>   mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin
>   'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

That means that I fixed nothing by working on mysql workbench and in my.ini file.

How can I get my Django connected with my mysql database and my server running?

Is there a way to establish the server connector using pymysql connector instead that mysql connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it.

By following this thread

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21740692/7658051

In settings.py, at the DATABASES entry, I substituted

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'
```

with

```
'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
```

and again, as specified here,

https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/checks.html#django-mysql-w003-utf8mb4

i added also

```
'OPTIONS': {
            # Tell MySQLdb to connect with 'utf8mb4' character set
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
        # Tell Django to build the test database with the 'utf8mb4' character set
        'TEST': {
            'CHARSET': 'utf8mb4',
            'COLLATION': 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        }
```

and then if I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It seems to work, even if I cannot access http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin , because I am connected to a legacy database, so I still have to inspect db and stuff I still have to learn.

As second proof that the connection is now working, when I run

```
connect_to_mysql_2.py
```

(See [(2059,“Authentication Plugin 'caching_sha2_password'”) when running server connected with MYSQL database on Django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54633968/7658051))

I finally get

> mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object at 0x000001DFB7521550

So I really think this time the connection is on.

Comment: I had a horrible experience by trying to use mysql with python. I would recommend instead to use postgresql

Comment: using that engine seems to yeild the following error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a problem in your python code, but in the python connector. The `caching_sha2_password` plugin is now the default auth plugin and clients have to support it in order to connect. So, the best solution is to update your python connector. An alternative way is to disable this plugin, but that's something I don't recommend as it lowers your server's security.

Comment: I installed 
mysql-connector-python-8.0.15-py3.7-windows-x86-64bit.msi 
from 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ 
but when I try to run the server, I get the same error again

Comment: You should use `pip install mysql-connector-python` instead.

Comment: Still nothing changes: it says " Requirement already satisfied: ..."

Answer (score 1):

[PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/CHANGELOG) added support for `caching_sha2_password` in 0.9.0, though there was a Py2 error fixed in 0.9.1.

Also noted in the [install instructions](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/docs/source/user/installation.rst), for `caching_sha2_password` there is the additional requirement:

```
python3 -m pip install PyMySQL[rsa]
```